# undefined reference to `zmq_ctx_new' when compiling using makefile

Tags: makefile, zeromq, jetson-xavier

I installed zmq on my linux-ubuntu flavoured NVIDIA Jetson Xavier as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev
```

I created a simple ZMQ server that uses PUSH/PULL architecture in a C++ program. I am able to compile it using CLI as follows:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g server.cpp -lstdc++ -lzmq -o out
```

Then I integrate this code in my larger application with more libraries and dependencies. This is compiled using a makefile (`makefile.config`). To compile the updated application, I need to add the `-lzmq` flag to the original makefile. This is what I do:

```
-COMMON_FLAGS += -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -std=c++11 $(INCPATHS)
+COMMON_FLAGS += -Wall -g -lstdc++ -lzmq -Wno-deprecated-declarations -std=c++11 $(INCPATHS)
```

But on running `sudo make clean && sudo make`, I get

```
Linking: ../../bin/sample_uff_mask_rcnn_debug
../../bin/dchobj/sampleUffMaskRCNN.o: In function `main':
/home/virus/Desktop/optimisation/custom-inference-mrcnn/maskRCNN/sampleUffMaskRCNN.cpp:717: undefined reference to `zmq_ctx_new'
/home/virus/Desktop/optimisation/custom-inference-mrcnn/maskRCNN/sampleUffMaskRCNN.cpp:718: undefined reference to `zmq_socket'
/home/virus/Desktop/optimisation/custom-inference-mrcnn/maskRCNN/sampleUffMaskRCNN.cpp:724: undefined reference to `zmq_ctx_new'
/home/virus/Desktop/optimisation/custom-inference-mrcnn/maskRCNN/sampleUffMaskRCNN.cpp:725: undefined reference to `zmq_socket'
/home/virus/Desktop/optimisation/custom-inference-mrcnn/maskRCNN/sampleUffMaskRCNN.cpp:726: undefined reference to `zmq_connect'
/home/virus/Desktop/optimisation/custom-inference-mrcnn/maskRCNN/sampleUffMaskRCNN.cpp:737: undefined reference to `zmq_recv'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Makefile.config:301: recipe for target '../../bin/sample_uff_mask_rcnn_debug' failed
make: *** [../../bin/sample_uff_mask_rcnn_debug] Error 1
```

The Makefile is simple

```
OUTNAME_RELEASE = sample_uff_mask_rcnn
OUTNAME_DEBUG   = sample_uff_mask_rcnn_debug
EXTRA_DIRECTORIES = ../common
.NOTPARALLEL:
MAKEFILE ?= ../Makefile.config
include $(MAKEFILE)
```

---

The original `makefile.config` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/VsAV5YKG)

I feel that I am messing up with the makefile because zmq works when compiling using `gcc`.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question or shown a problem here.

Comment: Sorry for missing it. I updated the question

Comment: Well, we have no idea what your makefile does.  However, it's almost certainly wrong to add libraries to a variable named `COMMON_FLAGS` as they should only be put into the link line, not the compile lines; the presence of `INCPATHS` here implies these flags are added to compile lines.  Secondly, the order of libraries is critically important: they must come AFTER all the object files.  So in short, this is the wrong variable to add linker options like `-lzmq` to.  You'll have to find the variable containing libraries to link.  And, you should not add `-lstdc++` to your link line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as @madscientist pointed out, I was wrongly adding the linker flag `-lzmq` to the compiler line, which was meant to only contain compilation flags and not linker flags.

This is the change I made:

```
 COMMON_LIBS += $(CUDART_LIB)
+COMMON_LIBS += -lzmq
```